# Python Gymnasium change render mode

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

The following link describes the new gymnasiums inability to change render_mode

https://younis.dev/blog/render-api/

So I am looking for a work around.

In the gym API you used to be able to write code like the following which allows you to audit how your training is going on during a long training loop

```
   import gym
   import numpy as np

   env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0")

   .
   .
   .
   for episode in range(EPISODES):
    .
    .

       if episode % SHOW_EVERY == 0:
           render = True
           print(episode)
       else:
           render = False

       while not done:
       .
       .
        
          if render:
             env.render()
       .
       .
```

The only way I can replicate this is to close the environment and remake it.
eg

```
.
.
.
if episode % SHOW_EVERY == 0:
    env.close()
    env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0",render_mode='human')
           
    print(episode)
else:
    env.close()
    env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0")
.
.
.
.
```

Is there a better way?